# não consigo baixar pygame

Tags: python

galera, estava tentando baixar o pygame pelo pycharm porém fica dando falha o tempo todo, alguém sabeq o por que? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Como pergunta o erro que lhe apareceu, tem a versão do pip atualizada ? Confirme e/ou atualize se for caso disso. Em windows seria algo como `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 2):

O erro diz que você está digitando o comando de instalação no campo errado.
Se você instalou o python da forma padrão (linkando ele nas variáveis de ambiente)

Basta você abrir o CMD (Windows+R | CMD | [Enter]) e digitar:

**pip install pygame** [Enter]

Pronto, o próprio python irá baixar/instalar no diretório correto

Answer (score 0):

Como não sei qual o método que você usou, vou dar os 2 melhores, na minha opinião:

### Método automático

1. Use o atalho **`Ctrl + Alt + S`** para entrar nas configurações
2. Vá em **`Project: Nome_do_Projeto`**
3. Clique em **`*Project Interpreter`**
4. CLique no botão de **+** verde
5. Procure pelo Pygame e clique em  **`Install Package`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Método Manual

Se não der dessa maneira sugiro baixar e instalar manualmente o Pygame através [deste link](http://programarcadegames.com/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.4.msi).

Após instalar verifique se o pacote está atualizado. (Se não estiver uma flechinha azul vai aparecer quando você selecionar o nome do pacote)